# prove an operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact space and $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure on $X$. Let $T\in B(L^{p},C(X))$ where $1<p<\infty$. Show that if $A:L^{p}\rightarrow L^{p}$ is defined by $Af=Tf$, prove that $A$ is a compact operator.

Let $i:C(x)\rightarrow L^{p}$ is an embedding. So $A$ is in fact $i\circ T$. Since compact operators consist a closed ideal, as long as we can prove either $i$ or $T$ is compact we are done. But I have a hard time proving it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume $L^p$ means $L^p(X).$

It is not true in general that $i$ or $T$ is compact.

I suggest starting by taking a sequence $Af_n$ and trying to show there is an $L^p$ convergent subsequence $Af_{n_k}.$ To achieve this, first try to conjure a subsequence such that $Tf_n$ converges pointwise on $X$ - think of what kind of operator $f\mapsto (Tf)(x)$ is. Then you just need a theorem that turns this pointwise convergence into $L^p$ convergence.